# Centering an individual, fixed DIV block, not its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

-I created a navbar using a Div

-I have specified a width/height for it

-I have adjusted the padding values to make it look nice

-I have set "top" to 0, to eliminate any leakage while scrolling through the page

-I have set a fixed position, so that it always stays at the top of the page, while the User is scrolling down on the page


**How in the world can I center the DIV block (while not adjusting the elements inside)?** I tried the "center" tag but to no avail.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div align=right style="width:465px;padding-top:10;padding-right:20;top: 0;height:40px;position: fixed;background-color:#ff0000">
logo image here
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the love of readability, do not use inline styling like that.

Comment: Its OK to provide inline styling for presenting the problem. In fact, it is better that way for asking a question.

Comment: @RUJordan: As Samir said, this was purely done for readability.

Comment: @Samir it's not a better way to ask a question. Inline anything is poor readability, and in general poor programming. It's more difficult to read a sentence of CSS than a nice list of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left` and `right` set to '0' and `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto` to center a `fixed` or `absolute` positioned item:

### HTML

```
  <div align=right class="nav">
    logo image here
  </div>
```

### CSS:

```
.nav{
    /* original: */
    width:465px;padding-top:10;padding-right:20;top: 0;height:40px;
    position: fixed;background-color:#ff0000;

    /* New code to center it: */
    left: 0; right: 0; margin:0 auto;
}
```

Live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lxonm

Comment: Thank you. Simplest and easiest solution! :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a fixed width, just use:

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-242.5px;
```

The margin here being equal to half the total width of 485 pixels including 20px of horizontal padding.

Comment: There we go.  I'm gonna post my version though cuz I like it better lol

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it, then center it.

## [JSBin Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/ujegObiQ/1/edit)

### HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
 }
 .inner {
    width: 465px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 auto
 }
```

Comment: Adding HTML to solve a layout problem is nearly always a bad idea when better solutions are available.

Comment: Normally I agree but if he wants more things to be sticky up top and still maintain a constant height or style, this is the easiest way.  But the other answers here are also valid of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 margin:0 auto;
```

This should horizontally center your Div.

EDITED: Yes, not in fixed position.

Comment: Not in fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, if you don't know element dimensions

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Doesn't work on IE8, requires `-webkit-` prefix for all webkit based browsers and `-ms-` prefix for IE9. For that simple case (centering fixed width div) there are better solutions.

Comment: As long as you [include `-webkit` and `-ms` prefixes and don't care about IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d).

Answer (score 0):

This wil work also:

```
.blaat {
width:465px;
padding-top:10;
padding-right:20;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
height:40px;
position: fixed;
background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

Here's [the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ7GZ/)..